# TFS2012 Is it possible to prune a branch off the base and re-attach one layer down

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branching-and-merging, source-control-explorer

I have the following tree in TFS2012

```
Base-->Branch1-->Dev1
 |
 \/
Dev2
```

I want to reparent Dev2 from Base to Branch1 so that the new tree will look like this:

```
Base-->Branch1-->Dev1
          |
         \/
        Dev2
```

Possibly important detail: Base and Branch1 are *identical* in every way.  The only item in the history for Branch1 is its original creation from Base.  Dev1 and Dev2 both have significant changes but are effectively based off the same original.

Is there any way to accomplish this *without* using a baseless merge?

Alternatively, if I create a new branch Dev3 off of Branch1, is there any way to apply all of the change sets from the history of Dev2 to Dev3.  This would, in theory, result in Dev3==Dev2.  I could then delete Dev2.

Comment: Why don't you want to use baseless merge?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I don't want to use a baseless merge because there will be a *lot* of conflicts to resolve as Dev2 has had radical surgery to the folder structure and code.  Since the parent of Dev2 (Base) is identical in every way to Branch1 (sibling of Dev2), if there was some way to shelve all the change sets from Dev2 and then apply the shelved change sets to a new branch off Branch1, that'd save me days of work.  One suggestion I've seen is to rollback and undo the rollback but shelve the undo, but that would pollute the change history.  Hoping there's a better option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use baseless merge to create relationship between Branch1 and Dev2, then reparent Dev2 by right click Dev2 branch and select Reparent (reparent to Branch1) as the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: As I specifically requested a solution *not* using baseless merge in my original post (reason cited in my comments on the post), I cannot mark this as the correct solution.

Comment: Migrate changesets from one project to another (two different projects) doesn't make sense, as the changesets apply for the source project, not target project. If you want to keep the changesets, I'm afraid you need to solve the conflicts by taking the Branch1 version.

Comment: My key point here is that Branch1 and Base are identical.  So *in theory* applying the same change sets that resulted in the delta between Base and Dev2 to a new branch (Dev3, say) off Branch1 should result in Dev3==Dev2.  Based on my research thus far, the least painful way to do this is rollback Dev2 to original Base, undo the rollback, shelve the rollback changes and then apply the shelved undo to Dev3.  That would pollute the history, but from what I understand that's going to happen anyway using a baseless merge.